# MCU slave receiver I2C shifts incoming data by one bit when replying with ACK

Tags: raspberry-pi, c, atmega328p

I am communicating with I2C/TWI between a MCU ([Atmega328p](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf)) as Slave receiver and the raspberry pi 5 as master transmitter. I2C is at 100kHz configuration (the slower the Rpi5 can go).

I have an issue when, if my MCU after it receives the transmitted byte and replies with ACK , it looks like it shifts the whole received byte by 1 bit to the left. Example: 0xFF (11111111) is sent, the MCU receives 0xFE (11111110).

If, after the MCU receives a byte, responds with NACK, the MCU reads the byte as normal, I do not face any issue using NACK. And I cannot understand why is that.

I looked at it on the oscilloscope. 0xFF is sent from the PI, and the two plots are:

When NACK returned from the MCU:
[image: Nack Returned]

When ACK returned from the MCU:
[image: ACK returned]

Plots look fine and since this is the only issue with the I2C bus, makes me believe that the MCU's firmware is not correct.

Raspberry pi's software: (writes the data, shows error only when MCU replies with NACK, but data are send correctly as shown in the oscilloscope):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/i2c-dev.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() 
{
    printf("make file\n\r");
    int file;
    printf("Make filename\n\r");
    char filename[] = "/dev/i2c-1";
    printf("Pick address\n\r");
    int addr = 0x08;  // Replace with your I2C device address
    
    uint8_t buffer[1];
    buffer[0]=0xFF;

    printf("Open the I2C device file\n\r");

    // Open the I2C device file
    if ((file = open(filename, O_RDWR)) < 0) {
        perror("Failed to open the I2C bus");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Set the I2C device address\n\r");
    // Set the I2C device address
    if (ioctl(file, I2C_SLAVE, addr) < 0) {
        perror("Failed to acquire bus access and/or talk to slave");
        return 1;
    }
       
    printf("Write data\n\r");
    // Write data
    // Example: Writing a single byte
    if (write(file, buffer, 1) != 1) {
        perror("Failed to write to the I2C bus");
        return 1;
    }
       
    return 0;
}
```

MCU's I2C setup:

```c
    BIT_SET(SREG, BIT(7));//Interrupt bit in SREG set
    //slave
    TWAR = 0B00010001;//Device’s Own Slave Address is 0x08 (0001000X), responds to general call(XXXXXX1)
    BIT_CLEAR(TWCR, BIT(TWIE));//I2C Interrupt disable
    BIT_CLEAR(TWCR, BIT(TWSTA));//Clear TWSTA to become slave
    BIT_CLEAR(TWCR, BIT(TWSTO));//Stop condition disabled
    BIT_SET(TWCR, BIT(TWEA));//acknowledge own address
    BIT_SET(TWCR, BIT(TWEN));//TWI Enable
```

MCU's Main Loop (the "sw" function is serialWrite to the COM port of the MCU):

```c
    /*After its own slave address and the write bit have been received, the TWINT Flag is set and a valid 
    status code can be read from TWSR*/
    if (BIT_GET(TWCR, BIT(TWINT)))//if TWI interrupt flag is set
    {
        
        static uint8_t twStatus,receivedData;
        
        twStatus = TWSR;//read the status
        BIT_CLEAR(twStatus, BIT(0));//clear prescaler values
        BIT_CLEAR(twStatus, BIT(1));
        sw("TWSR status code is ",1);
        swn(twStatus,16,0,1); //serialWrite the current status
        sw(":->",1); //serialWrite
                
        //Slave receiver
        if (twStatus == 0x60)
        {
            sw("Own SLA+W received, ACK returned\n\r",1);
            BIT_CLEAR(TWCR, BIT(TWSTA));
            BIT_CLEAR(TWCR, BIT(TWSTO));
            //Data byte will be received and ACK will be returned.
            BIT_SET(TWCR, BIT(TWEA));
        }
        else if (twStatus == 0x80)
        {
            sw("Prev addressed with SLA+W, data received, ACK returned\n\r",1);
            BIT_CLEAR(TWCR, BIT(TWSTA));
            BIT_CLEAR(TWCR, BIT(TWSTO));
            //Data byte will be received and ACK will be returned.
            BIT_SET(TWCR, BIT(TWEA));   
            
            sw("Data: ",1);
            receivedData = TWDR;
            swn(receivedData,16,1,1);
            sw("\n\r",1);                   
        }
        else if (twStatus == 0x88)
        {
            sw("Prev addressed with own SLA+W, data received, ACK returned\n\r",1);
            //Switch to non addressed slave, Own SLA recognized.
            BIT_CLEAR(TWCR, BIT(TWSTA));
            BIT_CLEAR(TWCR, BIT(TWSTO));
            BIT_SET(TWCR, BIT(TWEA));       
            
            //sw("Data: ",1);
            receivedData = TWDR;
            swn(receivedData,16,1,1);
            sw("\n\r",1);
        }
        else if (twStatus == 0xA0)
        {
            sw("Stop or repeated start received while being slave.\n\r",1);
            //Switch to non addressed slave, Own SLA recognized.
            BIT_CLEAR(TWCR, BIT(TWSTA));
            BIT_CLEAR(TWCR, BIT(TWSTO));
            BIT_SET(TWCR, BIT(TWEA));
            
            sw("Data: ",1);
            receivedData = TWDR;
            swn(receivedData,16,1,1);
            sw("\n\r",1);                       
        }
        
        /*clearing this flag starts the operation of the TWI, so all accesses to the TWI Address Register (TWAR), TWI
        Status Register (TWSR), and TWI Data Register (TWDR) must be complete before clearing this flag.*/
        BIT_SET(TWCR, BIT(TWINT));//WRITE 1 to TWINT to clear it
```

And the serial output of the MCU is:

TWSR status code is 60:->Own SLA+W received, ACK returned

TWSR status code is 80:->Prev addressed with SLA+W, data received, ACK returned

Data: fe

Side note: Because my MCU uses 5V logic while the Pi uses 3.3V logic, I use [LSF0102DCUR](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lsf0102.pdf?ts=1706517689166&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLSF0102)  to convert the 5V to 3.3V and vise versa. I was probing the side where the RPI is looking at on the above plots. The MCU's side is the same (no jittering or any funny business on the bus so I thought its not worth mentioning, I probe and leave the MCU's side (using ACK) below:

[image: MCU's side, with ACK]

Schematic/3D:

[image: 3.3V to 5V I2C]

Layout (I tried to put all the components as close as possible):
[image: I2C level shifter layout]

Wiring:
[image: I2C wiring]

Comment: @Justme done. I will take a better look at the level shifter and the bus signals then.

Comment: By the looks of it, you did not send either repeated start or stop bit immediately after the 2nd ACK/NACK.

Comment: @kaosad can raspberry pi send a Stop/start via software/code? It should be handled by the hardware. If you do know of a way to send the stop command after the ACK/NACK, let me know

Comment: By right the read()/write() functions should handle the stop bit for you. Looking at your CLK signal, it appears that the slave was holding it low thus preventing the master to continue clocking.

Comment: @ChristianidisVasilis I just saw this is a normal PCA9396-alike clone, so it should work; it does not have internal pull-ups or rise-time accelerators. However, the 1k resistors are quite extreme. They sum up to 8.3mA which is quite a lot more than 3mA rated for normal I2C standard. The MCUs should have no problem with that, but still. The pinout of having SDA and SCL right next to each other on PCB and on the cable shows, they are the extra spikes shown on scope and come from capacitive coupling. Still, RPi should be able to communicate standard transactions with start and stop.

Comment: @Justme When and if I can before the project's timeline ends, I will run the MCU with 3.3V and communicate directly to the Pi again. Until then I will just use NACK for the communication and ignore the Pi's I2C communication errors regarding the ACK. Tried with/without I2C interrupt function on the MCU's I2C, same effect. At the moment, the interrupt is deactivated.

Comment: You should get rid of those ugly bit handling macros in favour of plain, readable C. `BIT_CLEAR(TWCR, BIT(TWSTA));` is not readable by C programmers and they aren't interested in learning your local macro language. Whereas `TWCR &= ~TWSTA;` is readable and perfectly clear.

Comment: @Lundin you might be right, but CLEAR and SET are more readable than & and | to newbies. And I believe this is worth more than being readable from experts.

Comment: @ChristianidisVasilis No, they are more readable to non-C programmers. Do not write code to be read by non-programmers - why would non-programmers ever read code? Write code to be read by C programmers. It would actually appear that this macro language is one of the causes of the bug. Because had you used conventional C, you'd write something like `TWCR = THIS | THAT;` rather than a macro for every bit.

Comment: You might find the alternative bit masking style at the bottom of [How to access a hardware register from firmware?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276290/276294#answer-276294) interesting. That is, you could write macros enabling you to write something like `TWCR = TWSTA(0) | TWSTO(0) | TWEA(1);` if you find that form more readable. than just `TWCR = TWEA;`

Comment: @Lundin The bit set and clear macros are used because it was the Atmel AVR notation and early GCC compiler did not generate an opcode to set or clear a single bit if you used C logical operators to and/or a single bit. That code is perfectly readable to any AVR C programmer, but maybe not to a generic C or ARM C programmer. Bit macro is also used because Atmel headers used bit positions 0..7, not bit masks 0x01.. 0x80, and TWSTA is a macro with value of 7 so if you do what you recommend no one can use default AVR-GCC/Atmel/Microchip headers any more.

Comment: @Justme And that's just one reason why 30 year old MCUs shouldn't be used in new projects. I also recall some similar, very skunky non-standard way of setting/clearing bits used by the 8051 camp. Luckily these awful old MCUs ought to be dead and buried by now. Ought to...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the other answer that pastes the data sheet, the problem is now clear why clearing or setting bits individually to TWCR register did not work.

The TWINT bit will be set to logic 1 when TWI hardware has finished the current job and is waiting for software response.

The TWINT bit is used to start the next operation by clearing the bit to logic 0, but it is cleared by writing a logic 1 to this bit in the TWCR register.

So when you tried to set or clear any of the other bits, the TWCR register sees a read-modify-write sequence.

And it means that since the TWINT bit is high when reading, and you did not modify it, it is written back as high, telling the TWI hardware to continue with the next operation.

But since not all control bits were properly set before TWI hardware was told to start, and control bits are set after during the operation, the outcome of the operation will be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. The issue was on the MCU's firmware. I needed to set the whole TWCR register at once, not one bit at a time.

The datasheet of atmega328 states about TWINT flag in TWCR register:

> Also note that clearing this flag starts the operation of the TWI, so
> all accesses to the TWI Address Register (TWAR), TWI Status Register
> (TWSR), and TWI Data Register (TWDR) must be complete before clearing
> this flag.

[image: TWI atmega328p]

I find this misleading. It sounds like one can write the bits in TWCR register one by one and then clear the TWINT bit, but this is not the case.
In the datasheet also says:

> After all TWI Register updates and other pending application software
> tasks have been completed, TWCR is written. When writing TWCR, the
> TWINT bit should be set. Writing a one to TWINT clears the flag. The
> TWI will then commence executing whatever operation was specified by
> the TWCR setting.

[image: twi atmega328p]

Indicating that TWCR must be written as a whole byte at once, OR, (as I understand from the datasheet's examples as well), one can clear the TWINT bit only, which is the correct way to set the TWCR register.

What one should **NOT** do, is write the bits in TWCR one by one, and then clear the TWINT flag. (And this was my mistake there).

So my code changes as show. I commented out the part(s) where I set the bits one by one in the TWCR register, and I set those bits in `twcrMask` variable instead. Then, I load this variable in the TWCR register at once:

```
/*After its own slave address and the write bit have been received, the TWINT Flag is set and a valid 
status code can be read from TWSR*/
if (BIT_GET(TWCR, BIT(TWINT)))//if TWI interrupt flag is set
{
    
    static uint8_t twStatus,receivedData;
    //Add mask (or byte to be loaded to TWCR) here:
    static uint8_t twcrMask;
    twcrMask  = 0B00000101
    
    twStatus = TWSR;//read the status
    BIT_CLEAR(twStatus, BIT(0));//clear prescaler values
    BIT_CLEAR(twStatus, BIT(1));
    sw("TWSR status code is ",1);
    swn(twStatus,16,0,1); //serialWrite the current status
    sw(":->",1); //serialWrite
            
    //Slave receiver
    if (twStatus == 0x60)
    {
        sw("Own SLA+W received, ACK returned\n\r",1);
        //BIT_CLEAR(TWCR, BIT(TWSTA));
        //BIT_CLEAR(TWCR, BIT(TWSTO));
        //Data byte will be received and ACK will be returned.
        //BIT_SET(TWCR, BIT(TWEA));
        
        //Set the mask:
        BIT_CLEAR(twcrMask, BIT(5));//TWSTA
        BIT_CLEAR(twcrMask, BIT(4));//TWSTO
        BIT_SET(twcrMask, BIT(6));//TWEA
        BIT_SET(twcrMask, BIT(7));//TWINT
    }
    else if (twStatus == 0x80)
    {
        sw("Prev addressed with SLA+W, data received, ACK returned\n\r",1);
        //BIT_CLEAR(TWCR, BIT(TWSTA));
        //BIT_CLEAR(TWCR, BIT(TWSTO));
        //Data byte will be received and ACK will be returned.
        //BIT_SET(TWCR, BIT(TWEA));   
        
        //Set the mask:
        BIT_CLEAR(twcrMask, BIT(5));//TWSTA
        BIT_CLEAR(twcrMask, BIT(4));//TWSTO
        BIT_SET(twcrMask, BIT(6));//TWEA
        BIT_SET(twcrMask, BIT(7));//TWINT
        
        sw("Data: ",1);
        receivedData = TWDR;
        swn(receivedData,16,1,1);
        sw("\n\r",1);                   
    }
    else if (twStatus == 0x88)
    {
        sw("Prev addressed with own SLA+W, data received, ACK returned\n\r",1);
        //Switch to non addressed slave, Own SLA recognized.
        //BIT_CLEAR(TWCR, BIT(TWSTA));
        //BIT_CLEAR(TWCR, BIT(TWSTO));
        //BIT_SET(TWCR, BIT(TWEA));       
        
        //Set the mask:
        BIT_CLEAR(twcrMask, BIT(5));//TWSTA
        BIT_CLEAR(twcrMask, BIT(4));//TWSTO
        BIT_SET(twcrMask, BIT(6));//TWEA
        BIT_SET(twcrMask, BIT(7));//TWINT

        //sw("Data: ",1);
        receivedData = TWDR;
        swn(receivedData,16,1,1);
        sw("\n\r",1);
    }
    else if (twStatus == 0xA0)
    {
        sw("Stop or repeated start received while being slave.\n\r",1);
        //Switch to non addressed slave, Own SLA recognized.
        //BIT_CLEAR(TWCR, BIT(TWSTA));
        //BIT_CLEAR(TWCR, BIT(TWSTO));
        //BIT_SET(TWCR, BIT(TWEA));

        //Set the mask:
        BIT_CLEAR(twcrMask, BIT(5));//TWSTA
        BIT_CLEAR(twcrMask, BIT(4));//TWSTO
        BIT_SET(twcrMask, BIT(6));//TWEA
        BIT_SET(twcrMask, BIT(7));//TWINT
        
        sw("Data: ",1);
        receivedData = TWDR;
        swn(receivedData,16,1,1);
        sw("\n\r",1);                       
    }
    
    /*clearing this flag starts the operation of the TWI, so all accesses to the TWI Address Register (TWAR), TWI
    Status Register (TWSR), and TWI Data Register (TWDR) must be complete before clearing this flag.*/
    //Comment out the TWINT bit set here.
    //BIT_SET(TWCR, BIT(TWINT));//WRITE 1 to TWINT to clear it  
    //Load the mask/Byte at once:
    TWCR = twcrMask;
```

Comment: ""It sounds like one can write the bits in TWCR register one by one" Why would anyone do that, though. Register access should always be done as a single byte read or write. Realize that all registers are declared as `volatile` - access to them can't be optimized. So if you would set the bit one by one, you don't just change the meaning of the code but you also write to the register 8 times instead of one, which just slows down the program a lot for no good reason.

Comment: I think you can write the bits one at a time. The problem is that no matter which bit other than TWINT you accessed and which way you wanted to set it, the code performed a read-modify-write operation to the register, and TWINT will be read as '1', it will be also written back as '1', and TWINT is cleared by writing '1' to it so it started the operation even if you did not intend to. However, as said, I don't see why you would even want to write one bit at a time there, or even reading to a shadow register and flipping them individually before writing it back. Write directly what you need.

Comment: @Lundin I did not know that Lundin, thank you both!

Comment: @ChristianidisVasilis Writing to a temporary variable in RAM like in your answer is common good practice btw. Gather everything there, then just write to the actual register with a single instruction. Check out this example with full optimization for AVR https://godbolt.org/z/Tq111edro. I made up some bogus register but it doesn't matter. The first access bit by bit directly to the register results the majority of the generated code, whereas the instructions to a temporary RAM variable gets optimized into just some load, modify, store.